# sql query get row wise output of all occurences of similar string pattern from a varchar2 column

Tags: oracle

A oracle varchar column can contain multiple occurrences of values like `"N.S. Code 123" , "N S Code 678" , "N S Codes 567" , "N.S.Code  345"`, etc in same single column. Need a sql query for output as:

```
678
567
345
...
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Your question is a bit thin.

Comment: In the same *column* or same *attribute*? Are your strings formed `'N.S. Code 123'` or `'"N.S. Code 123" , "N S Code 678" , "N S Codes 567" , "N.S.Code  345"'`. If you are talking about one integer per string, then just use a string function to extract it from the string. You haven't explained what your problem is and where you are actually stuck.

Comment: Giving more detail, query to retrieve data for many columns from many joined tables & other columns are with one value, but one column (say table3.col) may have free hand text like "There are many NS Code NOS 1231 another N.S. Code No. 432421 and more N.S.Code Nos. 6676571 also N.S.Code No. 543 and there are some more N.S.Code 4232 and N.S. Code 62381 and HS Code Nos. 646482 and N.S Code No. 88921 and N S Code NO 12245 and N.S.Code: 7365 & N.S. Code: 4018768 and N. S. Code: 142365", so need to show all flavors of N S code in different rows with repeated same value of other table.cols, Pls help

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `CONNECT BY`.

Note : The pattern `\d{3}"` searches for exactly 3 digit number. However, if you have numbers with varying digits, you could just use `\d+`.

Also, It is unclear if you've got both these in your string : `"N S Code"` and `"N S Codes"`. Otherwise, I could have included to accommodate it in regex pattern.

```
WITH t (str)
     AS (SELECT '"N.S. Code 123" , "N S Code 678" , "N S Codes 567" , "N.S.Code  345"'
           FROM DUAL)
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                          '(\d{3})"',
                          1,
                          LEVEL,
                          NULL,
                          1)
      FROM t
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, '(\d{3})"');
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik for try, let me elaborate more.

Comment: Giving more detail, query to retrieve data for many columns from many joined tables & other columns are with one value, but one column (say table3.col) may have free hand text like "There are many NS Code NOS 1231 another N.S. Code No. 432421 and more N.S.Code Nos. 6676571 also N.S.Code No. 543 and there are some more N.S.Code 4232 and N.S. Code 62381 and HS Code Nos. 646482 and N.S Code No. 88921 and N S Code NO 12245 and N.S.Code: 7365 & N.S. Code: 4018768 and N. S. Code: 142365", so need to show all flavors of N S code in different rows with repeated same value of other table.cols